# Representing Möbius transform by a matrix

Tags: complex-analysis

So for each Möbius transform $g(z)=\dfrac {az+b}{cz+d}$ there is a corresponding nonsingular matrix $g=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{bmatrix}$. Since multiplying each constant in the transform by a nonzero constant doesn't change the transform but changes the matrix, we can restrict the matrix $g$ to be with determinant $1$. Now we have 1-1 correspondence between $g(z)$ and matrices $g$ with $\det g=1$.

Now, the group $G:=\Big\{\dfrac {z+b}{\bar bz+1};\ \ |b|<1\Big\}$ is a subgroup of the automorphism group of the unit disc. What is the corresponding representation matrix group of $G$?

I have tried $\Bigg\{\frac{1}{1-|b|^2}\begin{bmatrix} 1&b\\\bar b&1 \end{bmatrix}; \ b\in \mathbb C,\ |b|<1 \Bigg\}$ but I don't think this is  a group under multiplication! So how can I represent $G$ by matrices? And is $G$ semisimple?

Comment: The scaling invariance means the "matrices" are really elements of $\mathrm{PGL}_2$. So you can just represent them by $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & b \\ \bar{b} & 1 \end{array} \right)$, but just remember they are classes in the projective group.

Comment: But $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & b \\ \bar{b} & 1 \end{array} \right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & c \\ \bar{c} & 1 \end{array} \right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1+b\bar c & b+c\\ \bar{b}+\bar{c} & 1+\bar b c \end{array} \right)$ which is not of that form !!

Comment: Then how do you know $G$ is actually a group? By the exact same computation, the composition of two elements of $G$ looks like $\frac{(1+\bar{b}c)z+(b+c)}{(\bar{b}+\bar{c})z+(1+b\bar{c})}$, which does not appear to be the same form.